# Is it good to return html code to jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm working on a project where it has a number of pages. Each page displays 10 rows where the layout that is using for each page is different. Until now I had the html code of each row in a javascript code and based on the page's url I was using the appropriate html code (if statement). The if statement is inside into a loop which is looping based on the number of rows. The results of the rows are coming from an ajax method. Now I want somehow to separate it so it can be more easily for me to maintain it, basically to remove the html code from the javascript and keep each row's html code into a different file.

Note: the Ajax is in a given time, is sending automatically requests to the php file for any new rows.

One solution which I came out is that I can use the php to create a variable with the html code .

Second solution is to create an array of each record with the html code and then pass it to jquery to print it.

Both solutions I don't know if are good solutions and can help me to maintain the project in the future.

Comment: So, summarizing you have HTML templates in you JS code (stored in strings). Now you want to dynamically load HTML templates from other files (especially PHP files). Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: I think you need to create web service in php which will return you row. That is simple and dynamic approach. So if site is live and you want make changes then you can do it using database in back end.

Comment: @suvroc yes you are correct, I'm looking something like templating function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider a template library such as handlebars to help with templating. Frameworks such as AngularJS and Ember also excel at solving these kinds of problems.

Your Web Services API should be returning JSON though, not HTML fragments. Let the client build the DOM, and let the server focus on data.

Comment: what about mustache.js?

Answer (score 1):

You should return structured data (see [JSON](http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/) for example) to your AJAX request. This way, you can support multiple interfaces (e.g., a website, an application): each interface will get only the data, and will handle the rendering as it needs.

In your example, you ask for data via an AJAX request, your server responds with a JSON-structured response. JQuery reads it and converts it to javascript array thanks to [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). With your array, you loop through each element and insert html elements into the webpage.

Comment: GHugo this is what I'm doing now, I have the if statement with the html code inside the loop which reads each element and creates a variable with the html code. The problem is that is hard to maintain the html code, because the requirements are changing, therefore I'm looking a better way to handle the rendering method of the data that are coming from the AJAX request

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
If your HTML templates is not changing frequently, the best way is to define html templates in your HTML structure using some java script template library (eg. [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)) and fill it with data from your AJAX (JSON) requests.

If your HTML templates change frequently or depends on some conditions (data) in row, you should create PHP partial views which generate proper html structure already filled with data.

For many rows it is better idea to create whole table server side to reduce requests.